# Proving property of seminorm.

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

> Let $X$ be a topological vector space and $p$ be a semi-norm on $X.$ Show that the following statements are equivalent.
>
> $(1)$ $p$ is continuous.
>
> $(2)$ $p$ is continuous at $0.$
>
> $(3)$ The set $\{x \in X\ |\ p(x) \lt 1 \}$ is open in $X.$

How do I prove $(2) \implies (3)$ and $(3) \implies (1)\ $? If we can show that $(2) \implies (1)$ then we are done with $(2) \implies (3).$ Because the set in $(3)$ is just $p^{-1} (B(0,1)).$

$(2) \implies (1)$ is trivial. Because $p$ is same as a norm except the fact $p(x) = 0$ need not imply $x = 0.$ So it satisfies reverse triangle inequality i.e. $|p(x) - p(y)| \leq p(x - y),$ for all $x,y \in X.$ So we have $(2) \implies (3).$ How do I prove $(3) \implies (1)\ $?

Comment: Looks you already have $(2) \implies (1)$ and $(1) \implies (3)$, so you should try to prove $(3) \implies (2)$!

Comment: Yes you are right @diracdeltafunk.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: I proceed in the following way $:$ The set in $(3)$ contains the null vector **0**. Hence condition $(3)$ implies that there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of the null vector in $X$ such that for all $x \in U$ we have $p(x) \lt 1.$ So for a given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ we could take the open neighbourhood $V = \frac {\varepsilon} {2}\ U$ of the null vector in $X.$ Then for all $x \in V$ we have $p(x) \lt \varepsilon,$ proving that $p$ is continuous at **0**. Hence $(3) \implies (2),$ as required. **QED**

Comment: This works, but why have $U$ be arbitrary? There is a best choice for $U$, namely $p^{-1}(B(0,1))$. Also, you could use $\varepsilon$ instead of $\varepsilon/2$. Otherwise, very nice!

Comment: Yes you are right @diracdeltafunk. Thank you so much for your valuable suggestion.